# Sorting a 2D- Array

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort a 2D Array. I would like to sort the first column and then if the cell have the same value, then sorting with the second column.

I've tried to read all the answers already given in other posts. I have got no message errors but it's not just working at all.

My unsorted array is called tableautampon and I try to store the sorted result in tableautampon2.

```js
let tableautampon = [
    ['Thu Mar 21 2024 00: 00: 00 GMT + 0100(Central European Standard Time)',
        '{IR}',
        'AIBG ID',
        0.26568,
        '€',
        ['Regular Cash']
    ],
    ['Thu Mar 21 2024 00: 00: 00 GMT + 0100(Central European Standard Time)',
        '{SW}',
        'AXFO SS',
        4.25,
        'sek',
        ['Regular Cash']
    ],
    ['Thu Mar 21 2024 00: 00: 00 GMT + 0100(Central European Standard Time)',
        '{GB}',
        'BATS LN',
        58.8795,
        '£',
        ['Regular Cash']
    ],
    ['Fri Mar 22 2024 00: 00: 00 GMT + 0100(Central European Standard Time)',
        '{GE}',
        'AFX GY',
        1.1,
        '€',
        ['Regular Cash']
    ],
    ['Fri Mar 22 2024 00: 00: 00 GMT + 0100(Central European Standard Time)',
        '{GB}',
        'CBG LN',
        '',
        '£',
        ['Omitted']
    ],
    ['Fri Mar 22 2024 00: 00: 00 GMT + 0100(Central European Standard Time)',
        '{DE}',
        'DANSKE DC',
        7.5,
        'dkk',
        ['Regular Cash']
    ]
]

let tableautampon2 = tableautampon.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a[0] === b[0]) {
        return (b[1] - a[1]);
    } else if (a[0] > b[0]) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a[0] < b[0]) {
        return -1;
    }
});

console.log({tableautampon})
console.log({tableautampon2})
```

Comment: General programming note: there is no need for an "else" if your cases exit the function. `if (x) {return a;} else if (y) { return b; }` is the same as `if (x) return a; if (y) return b;`. That said, your code looks perfectly reasonable, so what are you seeing it do that you weren't expecting? And of course: can you show that off as [mcve] using a runnable snippet in your post?

Comment: Hello @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Thanks gor your time. I(ve edited my post to add a snippet. I've an issue with the var tableautampon. In my code, the variable was ok. The issue was the sorting. I aim to sort by first column and if the date are similar, then the second column

Comment: The google apps script Range class has a builtin sort function for that -[Range().sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)

Comment: I edited your code to make a snippet and added quotes in your array for the dates and bracket in the console.log

Comment: What's your question? Your code looks reasonable to me. Note that JavaScript `sort` modifies the array in place, so `tableutampon2 == tableutampon`.

Comment: `b[1] - a[1]` won't work, the second column is a string like `'{IR}'`, not a number. Use `b[1].localeCompare(a[1])`

Comment: You dates are not working for me this `new Date("Thu Mar 21 2024 00: 00: 00 GMT + 0100(Central European Standard Time)")` always returns `Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 GMT-07:00 1969` so it's out of the date range for Javascript dates so something is wrong with you data.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thanks for your comment. You are right it's unecessary to create a new variable as sort function modifies the array in place

Comment: with your help, I've performed more test. I think the issue is when I'm comparing the dates in my first column.   if((a[0] === b[0])) is always false. I don't understand why? Because, when I'm displaying the value with console.log I've got exactly the same output

Comment: Hi @Cooper, these values are the ones extracted from a column in the googlesheet. The initial input iin the cell is "21/03/2024". I've made a change in my local time to be able to compare these values with the function today()

Comment: When you use `===` with `Date` objects, it performs an identity comparison, it's not comparing the time value. So two dates that refer to the same time will not be equal.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by identity comparison? I assume that identity doesn't mean Date (as in that case it will always be equal).

So how should I make the comparison please? If it's the same calue, I would like to test the second condition to sort the array

Comment: It means the address of the object, instead of the contents. The same reason you can't compare two arrays with `==`. `[1, 2] == [1, 2]` is false.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. So what should I do to get the content and compare them please?

Comment: @Sébastien Chevin please provide the full code, its logs and the array you want to get

Comment: Hi @antonia, the fill doe is available in the snippet above. The desired result is row3, row1, row2, row6, row5, row4 of the initial array tableautamon created at the beginning. I try to sort the first element of row (which is a date) and if it's equal, then the second element of row in alphabetical order - {IR},{SW},{GB} for the 21th of March-